# I keep getting an error when i use Arrays.toString() method

Tags: java, arrays

```java
public class GFG { 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        int[] intArr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; 
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArr)); 
    }
    
}
```

Result:

```
/GFG.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(boolArr)); 
                   ^
  symbol:   variable Arrays
  location: class GFG
1 error
```

I tried a number of times and keep getting this error.
What's the issue here?

Comment: Have you imported `Arrays`?

Comment: @akuzminykh  no i havent,how do i do that? and how do i know what to import? new to java, have no idea

Comment: Add `import java.util.Arrays;` above the code you posted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider that, this is not a professional explanation. But this will help you to understand what is going on.

You get this error because you have no import the `Arrays` class into your code. The `Arrays` is not a keyword. It's a Class. Since it is not a keyword, the compiler doesn't know the implementation of that. So you have to import the implementation of that code. That means you have to tell the compiler, hey this is the meaning of `Arrays`. Then the compiler knows what to do with `Arrays`.

Add the following line to the top of your code.

`import java.util.Arrays;`

Now the compiler knows the meaning of the `Arrays`.

Answer (score 3):

`import java.util.*` in your code.

Like this

```
import java.util.*; 
public class GFG { 
   public static void main(String[] args) 
      { 
         int[] intArr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };            
      
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArr));             
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `import java.util.Arrays`

```
import java.util.Arrays
public class GFG { 

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        int[] intArr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }; 
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArr)); 
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

import this package with class **Arrays**  as the first line of your code before class

**import java.util.Arrays;**